# How to add TimeSpans together using LINQ when in a Dictionary collection

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to group up all equal keys in a Dictionary and add their corresponding TimeSpans together using LINQ?

Something like this (but this doesnt work)

```
var p = myDictionaryStringTimeStamp.Sum(x => x.Value.Add(myTimeStamp);
```

Comment: try adding myTimeStamp.Ticks

Comment: what is `myTimeStamp`? you need to add `myTimeStamp` to each dictionary value ? and then take the sum of values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) LINQ method like this:

```
var totalTime = myDictionaryStringTimeStamp
    .Values
    .Aggregate(new TimeSpan(0), (p, v) => p.Add(v));
```