# Summing Datetime propertes for all records in a list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

In an action method I've got the following query:

```
var list = listWRUD.
                Join(db.UsersDetails,
                o => o.UserDetailsId, od => od.identtyUserId,
                (o, od) => new
                {
                    fname = od.FirstName,
                    lname = od.LastName,
                    UserDetailsId = o.UserDetailsId,
                    FocusStart = o.FocusStart,
                    FocusEnd = o.FocusEnd
                }).ToList()
```

It basically gives me a list with a lot of repetitive names.

What I want to achieve(and have no idea how) is another list of type `RolesUsersViewModel`:

```
public class RolesUsersViewModel
{
    public RolesUsersViewModel(string FirstName, string LastName, TimeSpan totalex)
    {
            fname = FirstName;
            lname = LastName;
            total = totalex;
    } 

    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan total{ get; set; }
}
```

My idea is, if the query gives me a list of three results, and two of them are results with the same name, in the end to have a list of View models with two entries in it, which will have the accumulated time.

Can somebody help somehow? Can this be done just with lambda?

Comment: You're looking for `GroupBy()`.

Comment: Who would that sum the DateTime props?

Comment: Use `Aggregate()`.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18455756/34397

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After joining two collections you can group results by first and last names, and calculate sum of time intervals:

```
from x in list
group x by new { x.fname, x.lname } into g
select new RolesUsersViewModel {
   fname = g.Key.fname,
   lname = g.Key.lname,
   total = g.Sum(x => x.FocusEnd - x.FocusStart)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i couldn't make this work. It says : There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter FirstName. I don't know why is that. I edited my question, so it contains the full viewmodel.

Comment: @RobertRoss that is because your `RolesUsersViewModel` is not having a default constructor.

Comment: @RobertRoss yes Abdul is right. Just add constuctor without parameters to you view model, or create it as `select new RolesUsersViewModel (g.Key.fname, g.Key.lname, g.Sum(x => x.FocusEnd - x.FocusStart))`

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Sergey is correct.

This answer is for the edited version of the question

The error you are getting is because of the absence of a default constructor when you have a parameterized constructor.

You can avoid it by either including a parameterless constructor in your ViewModel

```
 public RolesUsersViewModel()
{

}
```

OR by changing the query to

```
    from x in list
    group x by new { x.fname, x.lname } into g
    select new RolesUsersViewModel (g.Key.fname, g.Key.lname, g.Sum(x => x.FocusEnd - x.FocusStart));
```